# WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed() returns false if app reloaded

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a simple Worklight V6 app using Push on Android.  When the app starts up, it does a form based login against the SampleAppRealm. Then it subscribes if necessary:

```
function checkSubscribed() {

    var subscribed = WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed("myPush");
    alert("Is subscribed: " + subscribed);
    return subscribed;
}
WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function() {

    WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback("myPush", "PushAdapter",
            "MyEventSource", function(props, payload) {
                alert("Received message: " + props.alert);
            });

    if (!checkSubscribed()) {

        WL.Client.Push.subscribe("myPush", {
            onSuccess : function() {
                alert("subscription succeeded!");
            },
            onFailure : function() {
                alert("subscription failed!");
            }
        });
    }
};
```

This all works swell.  The app starts up, it logs in, onReadyToSubscribe() fires, it registers the callback, checks the subscription (which is false), and subscribes (which succeeds)

I can see the client subscription in the Worklight console, and if I call the adapter, I get  the notification in the app.

If I hit the home button to do something else on the phone, and then return to the app, it still knows that it is subscribed.  If I push a message when the app is in the background, I see it in the Android notification area, and see it in the app when I return to it.  All good.

The problem is when I am running the app, it is subscribed, and I hit the Android back button. The app closes, but the Admin console still shows a subscribed client, and in fact if I push a message with the app closed, it shows up in the Android notification area. (so far so good)

But when I start the app, it goes through the authentication steps, onReadyToSubscribe() fires, checkSubscribed() gets called and WLClient.Push.isSubscribed() returns false.

If I restart the phone with the app subscribed, when the app restarts, WLClient.Push.isSubscribed() returns false.

How do I get the correct subscription state when an app restarts?

Comment: My first question would be whether or not you are able to reproduce the same behavior if using the supplied push notifications sample project from IBM Worklight Getting Started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

It turns out that the problem was that My app was explicitly calling WL.Client.login("SampleAppRealm") when it started.  The application descriptor environment setting of a security test on the environment was not configured.

When I add the security test to the application descriptor, isSubscribed() returns the correct answer after an app is restarted.  The funny bit is that everything else having to do with Push worked fine with authentication simply triggered by WL.Client.login()

I can't find any documentation around this requirement for the setting in the application descriptor, so it is hard to make out whether this is user error.  At the least, the docs could be punched up in this area.